# how to ensure that each li in ul has same height for small screen sizes such as mobiles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I mean using vh works for large screen sizes like laptops but for smaller ones like mobiles, the height of the li is not maintained.

Is there a more efficient way than using media queries for varied screen sizes to ensure responsiveness?

Comment: What is the problem with media queries?

Comment: Why would you want to change the height? I think the width is more important for scaling with bigger/smaller screens.
Most of the time the height (almost every element in my website) have a fixed value. It's the width that has to be dynamic.

Comment: @SeReGa  there's no problem, just want to know if there's a more efficient way

Comment: @C4mps because the height of the li's in the ul are not the same when viewed on mobile. I mean when viewed on mobile the li's do not have the same height

Comment: I still don't see why you want to have a dynamic height, but as you wish. Media queries are definitely the best option here.

Comment: @C4mps That's exactly my issue that i dont want dynamic height but the li's are having different heights when viewed on mobile.

Comment: Just use a fixed height then? Make sure your height is the same in all media queries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185189/discussion-between-naru123-and-c4mps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media queries are the best option here and I think it's pretty efficient.

Another option is to use Sass, it's a more advanced CSS extension and it will allow you to use IF/ELSE statements in your CSS, in your case you can test on screensize.
Here's a link: https://sass-lang.com/